# Is it possible to add a bounty to someone else's question?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounty

If I find someone else's question and I'm very curious as to what the answer could be, how can I add a bounty to the question?

Comment: Oh snap... I see now some questions have a "add bounty" button. Does it only appear after 24 hours or something like that? Feel free to close/delete this question. Not sure what the etiquette is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "add bounty" button takes some time to appear - if I remember correctly it's only available 48 hours after the question was asked, regardless if you're the original one asking or anyone else.